# Sent CC and BCC in approval process notification email

Tags: visualforce-component, approval-process, notification, visualforce-template

I have a scenario that user will approve records through email and added to approver some other user will also notified in the same email.

As content also varies I Planned to user visualforce template. Is it possible to add CC and BCC also? will that reflected in records (approve/Reject) if the user replies to the email?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure I completely follow the use case.   1. Approval processes use Email alerts to send emails at various steps. Replying to a request-to-approve using Email Approvals will push the approval process along to its next step.  The user that responds with the Email Approval will be recorded as the approving/rejecting user provided they are an allowed approver for the step in question
 2. The VF Email template is just that - an email template. As such, it is not within its scope to specify to: cc: or bcc:

Comment: Follow the link for your Answer: [https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_visualforce_email_templates.htm&language=en_US](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_visualforce_email_templates.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: I think It is not possible, however you can create a custom vf and controller according to your requirement. You should also go through the [http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCC & CC is not possible in approver notification email. we have set up an email alert to send additional emails.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do too (if that functionality isn't used yet), is use the "delegated approver" field and then, on the user that is set as the delegated user, set the receive approval notification emails to "approver or delegated approver".

Also another option would be to set a certain field on the object you are approving to (for example) "waiting approval X" and then have a workflow that is triggered by this field to go and send the required e-mails.